# mapbox moveend trigger on click only

Tags: mapbox

Ive build a map with custom markers and popups just like in [this mapbox-tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/custom-markers-gl-js/). Besides I have a custom menu with links to fly to those locations and open the associated popups with moveend-event. This works fine so far.

Now I also have a link which zooms out again to fit all markers in viewport. But this also triggers the moveend-event if it gets clicked.

To understand what I mean: See fiddle and click "Washington" then "SF" then "Show all". I dont understand why moveend triggers with "Show all".

[Heres a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jn504r1q/5/)

**HMTL**

```
 <div id="map"></div>
 <div id="menu">
      <span class="link" data-lat="-77.032" data-lng="38.913" data-id="#marker0">Washington</span>
      <span class="link" data-lat="-122.414" data-lng="37.776" data-id="#marker1">San Francisco</span>
      <span class="showall">Show all</span>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
    center: [-100, 37.8],
    zoom: 0
});

var bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();

var geojson = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [{
            type: 'Feature',
            geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [-77.032, 38.913]
            },
            properties: {
                title: 'Mapbox',
                description: 'Washington, D.C.'
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'Feature',
            geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [-122.414, 37.776]
            },
            properties: {
                title: 'Mapbox',
                description: 'San Francisco, California'
            }
        }
    ]
};

geojson.features.forEach(function(marker, index) {

    // create a HTML element for each feature
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';
    el.id = 'marker' + index;
    // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
        .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
        .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({
                offset: 25
            }) // add popups
            .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>'))
        .addTo(map);
    bounds.extend(marker.geometry.coordinates);
});

function fitmarkers() {
    map.fitBounds(bounds, {
        padding: 120,
        speed: 1.6
    });
}

fitmarkers();

function triggermarker(id) {
    map.on('moveend', function() {
        $(id).trigger('click');
    });
}

function fadeoutpopup() {
    if ($('.mapboxgl-popup').length) {
        $('.mapboxgl-popup').fadeOut(300, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    };
}

$('.link').click(function() {
    $('span').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
    fadeoutpopup();
    var markerid = $(this).data('id');
    map.flyTo({
        center: [$(this).data('lat'), $(this).data('lng')],
        zoom: 11,
        speed: 3
    });
    triggermarker(markerid);
});

$('.showall').click(function(f) {
    fitmarkers();
    fadeoutpopup();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using? Why would triggering a `moveEnd` be a problem? In case you already are moving, this movement has to end, so that the new movement can start (zoom out to show all markers)

When checking your fiddle, it did only work for me after changing the padding to a smaller value than `120`:

```js
function fitmarkers(){
    map.fitBounds(bounds, {padding: 10, speed: 1.6});
}
```

Please see the working code below:

(Please be aware, that you have shared your Mapbox access token. I have removed it from below code, but others could use it to generate cost for you)

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Display a map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
  
#menu {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 padding:20px 40px;
 color:#FFF;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

#menu span {
 margin:0 20px 0 0;
 cursor:pointer
}

.link.active {
 pointer-events:none;
 color:orange
}

.marker {
  background-image: url('https://docs.mapbox.com/help/demos/custom-markers-gl-js/mapbox-icon.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
    
    .mapboxgl-popup {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-content {
  text-align: center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>




<div id="map"></div>
<div id="menu">
<span class="link" data-lat="-77.032" data-lng="38.913" data-id="#marker0">Washington</span>
<span class="link" data-lat="-122.414" data-lng="37.776" data-id="#marker1">San Francisco</span>
<span class="showall">Show all</span>
</div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
  center: [-100, 37.8],
  zoom: 0
});

var bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();

var geojson = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [{
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [-77.032, 38.913]
    },
    properties: {
      title: 'Mapbox',
      description: 'Washington, D.C.'
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [-122.414, 37.776]
    },
    properties: {
      title: 'Mapbox',
      description: 'San Francisco, California'
    }
  }]
};

geojson.features.forEach(function(marker, index) {

  // create a HTML element for each feature
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'marker';
    el.id = 'marker'+index;
  // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
  .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
  .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
    .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>'))
  .addTo(map);
  bounds.extend(marker.geometry.coordinates);
});

function fitmarkers(){
    map.fitBounds(bounds, {padding: 10, speed: 1.6});
}

fitmarkers();

function triggermarker(id){
    map.on('moveend', function(){
            $(id).trigger('click');
    });
}

function fadeoutpopup() {
    if ($('.mapboxgl-popup').length) {
            $('.mapboxgl-popup').fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove(); });
        };
}

    $('.link').click(function() {
    $('span').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass("active");
    fadeoutpopup();
        var markerid = $(this).data('id');
        map.flyTo({
            center: [$(this).data('lat'),$(this).data('lng')],
            zoom: 11,
            speed: 3
        });
    triggermarker(markerid);
        
    });
  
  $('span.showall').click(function(f) {
        fitmarkers();
    fadeoutpopup();
    });
    
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. Changing the padding has no effect at all. I still don´t understand why triggermarker() triggers even when "showall" is clicked. The behavior is in all browsers Ive tested the same. Pls see this screencast to understand what I mean: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14P8tDrpOI_iaKbjqxOtVWgDxzvm0i_yM